# Can I generate random matrix value (decimals) in Python which the equal of each rows equal to 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### For the example:

I have matrix (1x4):

[0.3452 0.3274 0.1637 0.1637] => equals 1.
How can randomize 1 into matrix (1x4) in python? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create random values, and then just normalize by the sum of the values.

```
import random

x = [random.random() for _ in range(4)]
y = [(a / sum(x)) for a in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

from numpy use dirichlet.

You can change the size by changing the numbers. 
the "size=" will control the # of rows and the number in parenthesis will control the number of columns. The result will give you an array.

```
 import numpy

numpy.random.dirichlet(numpy.ones(4), size=1)
```